# How to wait for eclipse workspace job to finish before running another?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

job1 issues a remote command and I would like to print the results to the console.

job2 will then issue a local command and also print results to the console.

I've tried join() but I only get console output after everything is done.

```
public class MyHandler extends AbstractHandler {
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();

public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {

    WorkspaceJob job1 = new WorkspaceJob("Execute job1") {
        @Override
        public IStatus runInWorkspace(IProgressMonitor monitor) {
            Console.printObject("DEBUG job1 start: " + now);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Console.printObject("DEBUG job1 end: " + now);
            return Status.OK_STATUS;
        }
    };
    job1.setUser(true);
    Console.printObject("Job 1 schedule");
    job1.schedule();
    // try {
    // job1.join();
    // } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
    //
    // e1.printStackTrace();
    // }

    WorkspaceJob job2 = new WorkspaceJob("Executing job2") {

        public IStatus runInWorkspace(IProgressMonitor monitor) {
            Console.printObject("DEBUG job2 start: " + now);
            Console.printObject("DEBUG job2 end: " + now);
            return Status.OK_STATUS;
        }
    };

    job2.setUser(true);
    Console.printObject("Job 2 schedule");
    job2.schedule();
    // try {
    // Console.printObject("Job 2 wait..");
    // job2.join();
    // Console.printObject("Job 2 done...");
    // } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // e.printStackTrace();
    // }
    return null;
}
```

}

Comment: You should not be waiting as that will block the UI thread and  the GUI will freeze. Use a JobChangeListener to be notified when the job ends. What is `Console`?

Comment: I got it..thanks again greg! Console lets us print to different consoles.